# Performance issue with IN clause

Tags: oracle, database-performance, query-performance

I have question for using IN clause in sql query which of the following provide better performance

```
SELECT * FROM emp WHERE deptno IN (10,20)
```

OR

```
WITH dep AS (SELECT 10 deptno FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 20 deptno FROM DUAL)
SELECT * FROM EMP e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dep WHERE dep.deptno=e.deptno);
```

I am looking which will provide better performance

Comment: Often, joins can be better optimised than `IN` but you just have to analyse on a case by case basis. For your example, there's probably no difference in performance, but the first select makes your intent obvious and is easier to maintain. I don't know about Oracle, but in SQL Server, if emp was huge and there was a filtered index on deptno, the first one would probably be quicker

Comment: Your title is "performance issue with IN clause". If you have a performance issue that you want to solve then post the query plan

Comment: I think it's a near certainty that option 1 wins every comparison I can think of, especially readability, maintainability and performance. My question to you is why would you want to do anything different? It already ticks all the boxes. Option 2 is a train wreck. Even if it did "perform better" (which is impossible) I wouldn't do it because I wouldn't want train wreck code in my project.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian and Nick actually I am here trying to get opinion on performance of the queries. maintainability and readability is secondary part.

Comment: Also this an example on small set of data, I am looking for recommendation when  IN clause work with large data set

Comment: Basically... when you have index on the column being searched, and the data has high cardinality (lots of different unique values), then either way works. If you had an absolutely enormous in list then it might be quicker to put that in a table and index it.

Comment: If you run explain plan on even these two simple queries, then the first version has a lower cost. I cannot imagine why you would even think about the second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In clause" will be better choice because in another example optimizer can't figure out how to join this two tables so it scans all of the emp table and see if particularly record meets your condition. I've checked this on huge table (more than million rows) and the query plan was very different. Of course I assumed that you have index on deptno column. Without it both solutions require full table scan on emp table.

Comment: Thanks You. for clarifying the understanding